# How to create a NSPredicate for a Binary data containing a NSArray in CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I need to filter an entity by a binary data property that store a NSArray like the following one

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@{'description':'tag1'},
                     @{'description':'tag2'}]
```

And the Entity property is stored as NSKeyedArchiver:

`self.tags = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];`

Is it possible to create a NSPredicate that help me to filter that?

I have tried doing with `tags contains[cd] 'tag1'` but it doesn't run.

Comment: As Tom wrote, you can filter using the equality operators (>, <, ==, etc), though what anything other than `==` and `!=` means for a binary blob isn't really useful.  The best option, of course, is to store the tags as a proper to-many relationship, instead of stuffing them into a blob.

Comment: @Avi, my problem is that I can't change the model now. So I have to fight against this trouble. But As I comment to Tom, I will try to filter my entity using `NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:` and `NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` where I can define the condition to check if an object must be in my results or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use predicates to filter based on binary attributes. At least, `NSPredicate` is not going to help you, and neither is anything in Core Data. If it were an `==` predicate then it might work. Other than that, you *might* be able to find the right bit pattern to use in a filter, but you'd have to work out those bits for yourself based on some independent research. As a general rule though, Core Data binary attributes are not useful with predicates.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use `NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:` to use it with `NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` in order to filter my results. If I got a good solution, I will post it here